# reference problem in using sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I'm trying to use `sed` command to find/replace a pattern in file.
It gives:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 27: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

My command is:

```
sed 's/"([A-Z]+)",/"\1","\L\1"/g' file.txt
```

What is the problem?
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use:

```
sed 's/"\([A-Z]+\)",/"\1","\L\1"/g' file.txt
```

Notice the escaped parenthesizes with a "\".

Comment: Or with GNU `sed` just add the `-r` (or `--regexp-extended`) switch. Anyway, with basic regexp you have to escape the `+` too.

Comment: But I'm using `'` so i don't need escaping for shell itself. and for regex i'm using parenthesizes for grouping!

Comment: Those escaping are required by the basic regexp syntax. Not related to the used string delimiters – if you put the `sed` code in a separate file, the backslashes would be still required if you use basic regexp.